# Simple YAML parser for PHP

Tags: gratis, open-source, php, yaml

I'm looking for a simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) parser I can use in my PHP scripts. Requirements:

- **lightweight.** I don't want to install a complete framework just to parse a few simple YAML files.
- **independent.** I don't want some strange dependencies (like having to manually compile and install some system library first as PECL seems to expect), and I don't want to use special installers just to get it running (like Symfony expects me to use composer).
- **compact.** Ideally a single (class) file, maximally a small directory. Size should be in the kilobyte range (yes, 200k or even 400k would be OK, but rather not beyond that)

It's sufficient if it understands to **decode** YAML "objects" (i.e. the entire YAML fed to it as a string) and returns a PHP object/array representing it. Direct methods to just pass it a file name are nice-to-have (and easy to add by myself if missing). Manipulating and writing YAML isn't required, but welcome if above criteria are still met.

Ideally FOSS under an OSI license.